# Return false doesn't seem to interrupt this each() loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, return, each

I'm trying to validate a form with jQuery.

I'm looping all inputs in a table with `each()`. When clicking the save button, if one input is empty, simply the input should change border color to red. If all inputs are not empty, then the panel should animate and the alert message should show. But for some reason, if you leave any of the inputs empty, both conditions (if and else) happen. 
Please refer to jsfiddle.

Other similar posts like mine are fixed by adding return false to exit the each loop as soon as the if statement is met, but it doesn't work for me.
Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/KlaytonJames/rvh9Lwn0/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.edit").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents(".panel").addClass("rotate");
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("editable");
  })
  $("button.save").on("click", function() {
    $("table input").each(function() {
      var ret = true;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        ret = false;
        return false;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error").parents(".panel").removeClass("rotate");
        $("table tr").removeClass("editable");
        $(".alertbox").addClass("show");
      }
      return ret;
    });
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.edit").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parents(".panel").addClass("rotate");
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("editable");
  })
  $("button.save").on("click", function() {
    $("table input").each(function() {
      var ret = true;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        ret = false;
        return false;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error").parents(".panel").removeClass("rotate");
        $("table tr").removeClass("editable");
        $(".alertbox").addClass("show");
      }
      return ret;
    });
  })
})
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.panel {
 padding: 20px;
 background: pink;
}

.panel table {
 border: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.panel table th, .panel table td {
 border: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: left;
}

.panel table th {
 background: lightblue;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.panel table td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.panel table input {
 background: none;
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 display: block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 color: #000;
 width: 100%;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.panel table input.error {
 border-color: red;
}

.panel table button {
 background: none;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 transition: none;
}

.panel table button svg {
 fill: blue;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.panel table button.save {
 display: none;
}

.panel table .editable input {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 3px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 pointer-events: all;
}

.panel table .editable button.edit {
 display: none;
}

.panel table .editable button.save {
 display: block;
}

.panel.rotate {
 transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.panel.rotate .content {
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.alertbox {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 15px;
 left: 15px;
 right: 15px;
 border: 3px solid green;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #ccc;
 opacity: 0;
}

.alertbox p {
 color: green;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.alertbox.show {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="content">

    <!-- users details -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th colspan="2">Mobile</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <form>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="text" value="TestUser1" required></td>
          <td><input type="email" value="t1@gmail.com" required></td>
          <td><input type="tel" value="01234567" required></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="edit">
              <svg
                   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   id="svg8"
                   version="1.1"
                   viewBox="0 0 2.8923135 2.8889544"
                   height="2.8889544mm"
                   width="2.8923135mm">
                <defs id="defs2" />
                <metadata id="metadata5">
                  <rdf:RDF>
                    <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                      <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                      <dc:title></dc:title>
                    </cc:Work>
                  </rdf:RDF>
                </metadata>
                <g
                   transform="translate(-155.79194,-151.16862)"
                   id="layer1">
                  <path
                        style="fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1"
                        d="m 155.79225,154.05316 c 0,-0.0116 0.1084,-0.72009 0.1107,-0.72219 0,-0.001 0.142,0.13769 0.313,0.30864 0.1711,0.17094 0.3092,0.31081 0.307,0.31081 -0.01,0 -0.1649,0.0244 -0.3615,0.0543 -0.3941,0.0598 -0.3692,0.0565 -0.3692,0.0485 z m 0.4994,-0.49705 -0.3149,-0.31473 0.8777,-0.87709 0.8777,-0.8771 0.047,0.0468 0.047,0.0468 -0.8327,0.83223 -0.8327,0.83223 0.044,0.0432 0.044,0.0432 0.8325,-0.83187 0.8324,-0.83186 0.2262,0.22607 0.2263,0.22608 -0.8761,0.8754 c -0.4817,0.48148 -0.8774,0.87541 -0.8795,0.87541 -0.01,0 -0.1454,-0.14163 -0.3185,-0.31473 z m 1.8388,-1.83784 -0.3149,-0.31493 0.1014,-0.0998 c 0.1247,-0.12282 0.1461,-0.13492 0.2389,-0.13492 0.1028,0 0.1122,0.006 0.3228,0.21851 0.2038,0.20518 0.2056,0.20794 0.2056,0.31324 0,0.088 -0.014,0.11167 -0.1329,0.23332 -0.054,0.0547 -0.1,0.0995 -0.1018,0.0995 -0.01,0 -0.1459,-0.14172 -0.3191,-0.31493 z"
                        id="path1576" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="save">
              <svg
                   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   id="svg8"
                   version="1.1"
                   viewBox="0 0 2.892 2.9046745"
                   height="2.9046745mm"
                   width="2.892mm">
                <defs id="defs2" />
                <metadata id="metadata5">
                  <rdf:RDF>
                    <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                      <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                      <dc:title></dc:title>
                    </cc:Work>
                  </rdf:RDF>
                </metadata>
                <g
                   transform="translate(-155.64888,-150.73435)"
                   id="layer1">
                  <path
                        id="path1859"
                        d="m 155.84388,153.6352 c -0.06,-0.003 -0.084,-0.007 -0.099,-0.0172 -0.037,-0.0231 -0.061,-0.0496 -0.079,-0.0845 l -0.017,-0.0337 v -1.31508 -1.31507 l 0.015,-0.0284 c 0.022,-0.0421 0.062,-0.0801 0.098,-0.0943 0.024,-0.009 0.054,-0.0126 0.1218,-0.0126 h 0.089 v 0.52835 c 0.01,0.58758 0,0.55014 0.052,0.58155 0.022,0.0136 0.044,0.0139 0.9397,0.0139 0.8963,0 0.9174,-3.8e-4 0.9397,-0.0139 0.051,-0.0315 0.048,0.006 0.052,-0.58155 v -0.52835 l 0.092,1.7e-4 c 0.083,1.3e-4 0.096,0.002 0.1257,0.0168 0.044,0.0221 0.3269,0.30569 0.3501,0.35045 l 0.017,0.0321 v 1.18094 1.18093 l -0.015,0.0323 c -0.019,0.041 -0.055,0.0766 -0.095,0.0957 l -0.032,0.0149 -1.2416,3.7e-4 c -0.6829,1.6e-4 -1.2771,-0.001 -1.3204,-0.004 z m 2.373,-0.81268 v -0.54839 l -0.016,-0.0242 c -0.01,-0.0133 -0.03,-0.0315 -0.048,-0.0403 l -0.032,-0.0161 h -1.0244 -1.0245 l -0.032,0.0161 c -0.017,0.009 -0.038,0.027 -0.049,0.0403 l -0.016,0.0242 v 0.54839 0.54838 h 1.1202 1.1204 z m -1.9623,0.30399 c -0.038,-0.0259 -0.053,-0.0508 -0.053,-0.0898 0,-0.0424 0.019,-0.0774 0.053,-0.0973 0.024,-0.0144 0.032,-0.0145 0.8417,-0.0145 0.9137,0 0.8444,-0.004 0.8782,0.0508 0.031,0.0504 0.015,0.11619 -0.035,0.15079 l -0.024,0.0161 h -0.8185 -0.8185 z m 0.01,-0.47095 c -0.041,-0.0202 -0.068,-0.07 -0.061,-0.10807 0.01,-0.0342 0.033,-0.07 0.062,-0.0846 0.023,-0.0118 0.075,-0.0124 0.8431,-0.0106 l 0.8184,0.002 0.02,0.015 c 0.068,0.0508 0.062,0.14909 -0.011,0.18655 l -0.032,0.0161 h -0.8032 -0.8033 z m -0.066,-1.01613 c 0,-0.003 -0.01,-0.20661 -0.01,-0.4532 v -0.44835 h 0.2427 0.2426 v 0.45132 0.45132 l -0.236,0.002 c -0.1299,0.001 -0.2381,-3.7e-4 -0.2409,-0.003 z m 0.6991,-2e-5 c 0,-0.003 -0.01,-0.20658 -0.01,-0.45317 v -0.44836 h 0.4282 0.4282 v 0.45132 0.45132 l -0.4215,0.002 c -0.2318,7.3e-4 -0.4237,-3.7e-4 -0.4264,-0.003 z"
                        style="fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- success message -->
<div class="alertbox">
  <p>Your changes have been saved</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you leave second field empty, then `else` part will be executed first, and then on the next cycle `if` part is executed. I think everything works as written in your code (not in question description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First figure out which inputs are empty with `filter`. If that collection has `length > 0`, then those inputs are problematic - add `error` class to each of them. Otherwise, iterate through all inputs and remove the `rotate` class:

```
$("button.edit").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".panel").addClass("rotate");
  $(this).parents("tr").addClass("editable");
})
$("button.save").on("click", function() {
  const $inputs = $("table input");
  $inputs.each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("error");
  });
  const $emptyInputs = $inputs.filter((_, input) => input.value === '');
  if ($emptyInputs.length > 0) {
    $emptyInputs.each(function() {
      $(this).addClass("error");
    });
  } else {
    $($inputs[0]).closest(".panel").removeClass("rotate");
    $("table tr").removeClass("editable");
    $(".alertbox").addClass("show");

    // if you want to submit the form when the form is validated, remove this line:
    return false;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hymjknta/

```js
$("button.edit").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parents(".panel").addClass("rotate");
  $(this).parents("tr").addClass("editable");
})
$("button.save").on("click", function() {
  const $inputs = $("table input");
  $inputs.each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("error");
  });
  const $emptyInputs = $inputs.filter((_, input) => input.value === '');
  if ($emptyInputs.length > 0) {
    $emptyInputs.each(function() {
      $(this).addClass("error");
    });
  } else {
    $($inputs[0]).closest(".panel").removeClass("rotate");
    $("table tr").removeClass("editable");
    $(".alertbox").addClass("show");

    // if you want to submit the form when the form is validated, remove this line:
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.panel {
 padding: 20px;
 background: pink;
}

.panel table {
 border: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.panel table th, .panel table td {
 border: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: left;
}

.panel table th {
 background: lightblue;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.panel table td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.panel table input {
 background: none;
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 display: block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 color: #000;
 width: 100%;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.panel table input.error {
 border-color: red;
}

.panel table button {
 background: none;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 transition: none;
}

.panel table button svg {
 fill: blue;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.panel table button.save {
 display: none;
}

.panel table .editable input {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 3px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 pointer-events: all;
}

.panel table .editable button.edit {
 display: none;
}

.panel table .editable button.save {
 display: block;
}

.panel.rotate {
 transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.panel.rotate .content {
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.alertbox {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 15px;
 left: 15px;
 right: 15px;
 border: 3px solid green;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #ccc;
 opacity: 0;
}

.alertbox p {
 color: green;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.alertbox.show {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="content">

    <!-- users details -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th colspan="2">Mobile</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <form>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="text" value="TestUser1" required></td>
          <td><input type="email" value="t1@gmail.com" required></td>
          <td><input type="tel" value="01234567" required></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="edit">
              <svg
                   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   id="svg8"
                   version="1.1"
                   viewBox="0 0 2.8923135 2.8889544"
                   height="2.8889544mm"
                   width="2.8923135mm">
                <defs id="defs2" />
                <metadata id="metadata5">
                  <rdf:RDF>
                    <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                      <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                      <dc:title></dc:title>
                    </cc:Work>
                  </rdf:RDF>
                </metadata>
                <g
                   transform="translate(-155.79194,-151.16862)"
                   id="layer1">
                  <path
                        style="fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1"
                        d="m 155.79225,154.05316 c 0,-0.0116 0.1084,-0.72009 0.1107,-0.72219 0,-0.001 0.142,0.13769 0.313,0.30864 0.1711,0.17094 0.3092,0.31081 0.307,0.31081 -0.01,0 -0.1649,0.0244 -0.3615,0.0543 -0.3941,0.0598 -0.3692,0.0565 -0.3692,0.0485 z m 0.4994,-0.49705 -0.3149,-0.31473 0.8777,-0.87709 0.8777,-0.8771 0.047,0.0468 0.047,0.0468 -0.8327,0.83223 -0.8327,0.83223 0.044,0.0432 0.044,0.0432 0.8325,-0.83187 0.8324,-0.83186 0.2262,0.22607 0.2263,0.22608 -0.8761,0.8754 c -0.4817,0.48148 -0.8774,0.87541 -0.8795,0.87541 -0.01,0 -0.1454,-0.14163 -0.3185,-0.31473 z m 1.8388,-1.83784 -0.3149,-0.31493 0.1014,-0.0998 c 0.1247,-0.12282 0.1461,-0.13492 0.2389,-0.13492 0.1028,0 0.1122,0.006 0.3228,0.21851 0.2038,0.20518 0.2056,0.20794 0.2056,0.31324 0,0.088 -0.014,0.11167 -0.1329,0.23332 -0.054,0.0547 -0.1,0.0995 -0.1018,0.0995 -0.01,0 -0.1459,-0.14172 -0.3191,-0.31493 z"
                        id="path1576" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="save">
              <svg
                   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
                   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                   id="svg8"
                   version="1.1"
                   viewBox="0 0 2.892 2.9046745"
                   height="2.9046745mm"
                   width="2.892mm">
                <defs id="defs2" />
                <metadata id="metadata5">
                  <rdf:RDF>
                    <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                      <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
                      <dc:title></dc:title>
                    </cc:Work>
                  </rdf:RDF>
                </metadata>
                <g
                   transform="translate(-155.64888,-150.73435)"
                   id="layer1">
                  <path
                        id="path1859"
                        d="m 155.84388,153.6352 c -0.06,-0.003 -0.084,-0.007 -0.099,-0.0172 -0.037,-0.0231 -0.061,-0.0496 -0.079,-0.0845 l -0.017,-0.0337 v -1.31508 -1.31507 l 0.015,-0.0284 c 0.022,-0.0421 0.062,-0.0801 0.098,-0.0943 0.024,-0.009 0.054,-0.0126 0.1218,-0.0126 h 0.089 v 0.52835 c 0.01,0.58758 0,0.55014 0.052,0.58155 0.022,0.0136 0.044,0.0139 0.9397,0.0139 0.8963,0 0.9174,-3.8e-4 0.9397,-0.0139 0.051,-0.0315 0.048,0.006 0.052,-0.58155 v -0.52835 l 0.092,1.7e-4 c 0.083,1.3e-4 0.096,0.002 0.1257,0.0168 0.044,0.0221 0.3269,0.30569 0.3501,0.35045 l 0.017,0.0321 v 1.18094 1.18093 l -0.015,0.0323 c -0.019,0.041 -0.055,0.0766 -0.095,0.0957 l -0.032,0.0149 -1.2416,3.7e-4 c -0.6829,1.6e-4 -1.2771,-0.001 -1.3204,-0.004 z m 2.373,-0.81268 v -0.54839 l -0.016,-0.0242 c -0.01,-0.0133 -0.03,-0.0315 -0.048,-0.0403 l -0.032,-0.0161 h -1.0244 -1.0245 l -0.032,0.0161 c -0.017,0.009 -0.038,0.027 -0.049,0.0403 l -0.016,0.0242 v 0.54839 0.54838 h 1.1202 1.1204 z m -1.9623,0.30399 c -0.038,-0.0259 -0.053,-0.0508 -0.053,-0.0898 0,-0.0424 0.019,-0.0774 0.053,-0.0973 0.024,-0.0144 0.032,-0.0145 0.8417,-0.0145 0.9137,0 0.8444,-0.004 0.8782,0.0508 0.031,0.0504 0.015,0.11619 -0.035,0.15079 l -0.024,0.0161 h -0.8185 -0.8185 z m 0.01,-0.47095 c -0.041,-0.0202 -0.068,-0.07 -0.061,-0.10807 0.01,-0.0342 0.033,-0.07 0.062,-0.0846 0.023,-0.0118 0.075,-0.0124 0.8431,-0.0106 l 0.8184,0.002 0.02,0.015 c 0.068,0.0508 0.062,0.14909 -0.011,0.18655 l -0.032,0.0161 h -0.8032 -0.8033 z m -0.066,-1.01613 c 0,-0.003 -0.01,-0.20661 -0.01,-0.4532 v -0.44835 h 0.2427 0.2426 v 0.45132 0.45132 l -0.236,0.002 c -0.1299,0.001 -0.2381,-3.7e-4 -0.2409,-0.003 z m 0.6991,-2e-5 c 0,-0.003 -0.01,-0.20658 -0.01,-0.45317 v -0.44836 h 0.4282 0.4282 v 0.45132 0.45132 l -0.4215,0.002 c -0.2318,7.3e-4 -0.4237,-3.7e-4 -0.4264,-0.003 z"
                        style="fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </button>
          </td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- success message -->
<div class="alertbox">
  <p>Your changes have been saved</p>
</div>
```

You also might consider making the border width larger - `1px` of red may not be enough for the user to notice.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know about `filter()`, thank you for teaching me something new! As you can see I'm not a js master, but maybe one day I will be... =)